# Service oriented framework

Tags: java, c++, python, soa

Does anyone knows if there is a good service oriented framework (like Apache Thrift) that supports both C++, java and python with a similar set of features but with lighter requirement?

My main issue with thrift is that it requires boost (on the C++ side) that is a good, but too big, library.

Comment: Seems a bit like conflicting requirements. Boost is too big, but you need interfaces for three completely different languages?

Comment: I would like to generate the binding for those three languages (as for example in google protobuf) but not be forced to use boost while writing my code

Comment: @us2012 Would boost actually be "too big?" If you use static-libs, you shouldn't have to distribute it, and it should only include the features you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a few alternatives, although I can't speak for how they compare to Thrift.  All of these should have Java, C++, and Python implementations.

[Google Protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

[Apache Avro](http://avro.apache.org/)

[Hessian](http://hessian.caucho.com/)

Of the three, I think Google's Protobuf seems the most promising and [documented](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview?csw=1).